# How to implement Nebular NbTreeGridComponent with pagination

Tags: nebular

I want to implement NbTreeGridComponent along with Pagination.

I have created a data-table module/component separately and imported this component in another page.

After the table content is displayed I want to display some other content in same page and also apply pagination to this Data-Table.

Comment: I've had a hell of a time with this and it seems like there's very little info or community on this ui framework. Did you ever have any luck with this?